# Missing value - could not find unique third party identifier while instgram sso login

Tags: community, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement social login with Instagram to access community-

I have created auth provider as openId connect.

I have created auth provider class-

global class InstagramRegHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{

```
public static String ORG_SUFFIX = '@user.instagram.com';
private static final String DEFAULT_ACCOUNTNAME = 'Customers';
public static String EXTERNAL_USER_PROFILE = 'Customer Community User';
public static String TZSID = [SELECT timezonesidkey from User where profile.name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1].timezonesidkey;



global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){    

System.debug('Dumping Auth.UserData: ' + data);
System.debug('Registering Community user: ' + data.username);   

Auth.UserData d = normalizeUserData(data);

Id contactId;
contactId = createContact(d);
System.debug('Created contact: '+ contactId);            


Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name=:EXTERNAL_USER_PROFILE];
System.debug('Found profile: '+ p);


User u = createUser(d,p);

u.contactId = contactId;
return u;
```

}

```
global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    System.debug('Update User called for: ' + data.email);

    User u = new User(id=userId);
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    update(u);
}


private Auth.UserData normalizeUserData(Auth.UserData data){      


    String fullname = data.fullName;
    List<String> names = fullname.split(' ', 2);
    if (names.size() >= 2){
        data.firstName = names[0];
        data.lastName = names[1]; 
    } else {
        data.LastName = fullname;
        data.FirstName = 'Unknown';
    }


    data.email = data.username + ORG_SUFFIX;

    return data;
}

private Id createContact(Auth.UserData data){
    Contact c = new Contact();

    c.email = data.email;
    c.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    c.LastName = data.LastName;

    c.Description = data.attributeMap.get('bio');


    List<Account> accounts = [select Id from Account where Name =:DEFAULT_ACCOUNTNAME];

    System.debug('Found account: ' + accounts);

    c.accountId = accounts[0].Id;            
    insert c;

    System.debug('Contact created for ' + data.email + ' id=' + c.id);

    return c.id; 
}



private User createUser(Auth.UserData data, Profile p) {
    User u = new User();

    u.email = data.email;  
    u.username = u.email;
    u.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    u.LastName = data.LastName;

    String alias = data.username;
    //Alias must be 8 characters or less
    if(alias.length() > 8) {
        alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
    }
    u.alias = alias;

    u.languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.timeZoneSidKey = TZSID;
    u.profileId = p.Id;

    System.debug('User staged for ' + u.username);
    return u;
}
```

}

But I get the error Missing value - could not find unique third party identifier while instgram sso login

Comment: Can anyone have solution on this issue

Comment: Can anyone have solution on this issue